# AWS Cloudformation - How to store SSM value as per condition

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I am trying to use SSM using cloudformation template. However, I am not able to figure out how to store different value per environment based on condition.

Code Deployment pipeline passes `Stage` Parameter which I can use to understand to which envionment the code is being deployed.

```
Resources:
  SNSTopicName:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Description: SNS Topic Name
      Name: !Sub "/${Stage}/broker_name"
      Type: String
      Value: ""
```

How do I put condition for value based on `Stage` variable

Answer (score 2):

Following is one of the way;

I assumed you have Stage parameter defined like following, but if definition/declaration of `Stage` parameter varies for you. It will have no impact/change on related logic to figure out `Broker` shown below;

```
Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - tst
      - acc
      - prd
Mappings:
  Common:
    dev:
      Broker: Development
    tst:
      Broker: Test
    acc:
      Broker: Acceptance
    prd:
      Broker: Production

SNSTopicName:
  Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
  Properties:
    Description: SNS Topic Name
    Name: !Sub "/${Stage}/broker_name"
    Type: String
    Value: !FindInMap
      - Common
      - !Ref "Stage"
      - Broker
```

Where, Common is map with it's key as value of your Stage parameter and value is Broker